# How can I make 'pip' use the Python executable in the same prefix?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

I recently downloaded the Windows MSI installer for Python 2.7.10 32bit (I use that specific version for compatibility reasons) and installed it with 'pip' enabled. The tool works fine, but it seems to have hardcoded the path to the Python interpreter to use:

```
C:\Python27-from-msi>scripts\pip list
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
pip (7.0.1)
setuptools (16.0)

C:\Python27-from-msi>cd ..

C:\>move Python27-from-msi Python27-from-msi-new
        1 dir(s) moved.

C:\>cd Python27-from-msi-new\

C:\Python27-from-msi-new>scripts\pip list
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python27-from-msi\python.exe"  "C:\Python27-from-msi-new\scripts\pip.exe" list'
```

Is there a way to make `pip` pick up the `python.exe` executable which is in the same prefix as `pip` itself (i.e. `..\python.exe` on Windows)?

For what it's worth, `easy_install.exe` behaves the same. I suppose that these executables are build at installation time using something like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), and this is done in a way which hardcodes the path to the Python interpreter.